# Load records to Existing table using SaveAsTable

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive

As `InsertInto` statement taking more time to run compare to `SaveAsTable`, I want to use `SaveAsTable` with below use case.

I am using spark version `2.2` and I would like to create my table with below mentioned structure in the beginning of my spark code. At last, I have my `DF(df_all_rec)` ready which I want to write into `test` table using `SaveasTable` with `Partition(my_part)` and with Text format.

```sql
create table test(a varchar(50),
b varchar(50))
partitioned by (my_part int) 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY '^'
  NULL DEFINED AS ''
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
```

Please suggest how to achieve that

```scala
df_all_rec.write.mode("overwrite")
```

...?

Comment: try using `mode('append')`

Comment: I tried append as well and getting the error 
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Requested partitioning does not match the table:
Requested partitions:
Table partitions: my_part